# Bash array values like variables inside loop

Tags: bash, array

Im trying double loop using array values like array names for loop

```
array1="name1 name2"
name1="one two"
name2="red blue"

for name in $array1
do 
  for value in $name
  do
    echo "$name - $value"
  done
done
```

I need to use 'name' to '$name' for use in 2nd loop, but this don't work for me.
How could I use value of array1 like the name of array inside 2nd loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not how you define arrays in `bash`.

```
a="foo bar"
```

defines a string/scalar variable. And using it as `$a` (unquoted) performs the split+glob operator which only makes sense for strings representing a `$IFS` separated list of file patterns.

In `bash`, arrays are defined as:

```
a=(foo bar)
```

So here, you'd want:

```
array1=(name1 name2)
name1=(one two)
name2=(red blue)


for name in "${array1[@]}"
do
  typeset -n nameref="$name"
  for value in "${nameref[@]}"
  do
    printf '%s\n' "$name - $value"
  done
done
```

`typeset -n` is a relatively recent addition to `bash` and declares a *nameref*, that is a variable that contains the name of another variable and when expanded actually refers to the named variable.

Comment: in the printf statement, `$name` prints first element of arrays.. how to print name1 and name2 instead?

Comment: @spasic. Ah good point, I missed that. See edit.

Comment: Nameref is a quite recent 4.3 option. Using Indirection instead: `nameref="${name}[@]"; for value in "${!nameref}"` works with bash from the very old version 2.0 of 1997.

Comment: Perfect !!! 
Now I undestand arrays better.
Thanks a lot Stephane...

Answer (score 2):

A simple change from `for value in $name` to `for value in ${!name}` will make your script work correctly:

```
array1="name1 name2"; name1="one two"; name2="red blue"

for       name  in $array1     ; do 
    for   value in ${!name}    ; do
          printf '%s - %s\n' "$name" "$value"
    done
done
```

However, it should be pointed that the variable called `array1` is an string, not an array, no at all.
If you wish to work with arrays:

```
#!/bin/bash

array1=(name1 name2)
name1=(one two)
name2=(red blue)

for       name  in "${array1[@]}"     ; do
          ref="${name}[@]"
    for   value in "${!ref}"          ; do
          printf '%s - %s\n' "$name" "$value"
    done
done
```

Indirection works from bash 2.0 (1997) and up. Instead of nameref which is a recent 4.3 addition.

Answer (score 1):

As Stéphane Chazelas points out, a list of words is not the same an array. However, you can use indirect expansion like this:

```
array1="name1 name2"
name1="one two"
name2="red blue"

for name in ${array1}
do
    for value in ${!name}
    do
        echo "$name - $value"
    done
done
```

In this case, `${!name}` introduces a level of indirection.